# Replacing the inner HTML with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

For a tag:

```
<div class="special_tag"></div>
```

I want a `tag.replace_inner_html('inner')` that results in:

```
<div class="special_tag">inner</div>
```

The best I know is `replace_with('inner')` which replaces the outer HTML.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to replace inner text, [set `string` attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-string):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''
... <div>
...     <div class="special_tag"></div>
... </div>
... ''')
>>> elem = soup.find(class_='special_tag')
>>> elem.string = 'inner'
>>> print(elem)
<div class="special_tag">inner</div>
```

---

If you want to add tag (or tags), you need to [`clear` contents](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#clear), and [`insert`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert) or [`append`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#append) them (Use [`new_tag`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautifulsoup-new-string-and-new-tag) to create tags):

```
>>> elem = soup.find(class_='special_tag')
>>> elem.clear()
>>> elem.append('inner')
>>> print(elem)
<div class="special_tag">inner</div>
```

Comment: What if you want to set `innerHtml` in the JS style, where it parses the string to HTML before assigning? e.g., `node.innerHtml = <span>my text</span>`

Comment: @BallpointBen, AFAIK, BeautifulSoup cannot handle js stuff. You may need library that can handle js: for example, `selenium`.

Comment: @BallpointBen: I was trying to figure this out too, you can use: `newContents = BeautifulSoup('<h1>this is a test</h1> and I hate stackoverflow', 'html.parser'); elem.clear(); elem.append(newContents)`. This should correctly set the inner HTML